# Disable restarting in PM2

Tags: node.js, pm2

I need to stop my nodejs app for some conditions.So I have used `process.exit()` method. I am running my app with PM2. But PM2 is restarting the app whenever it was stopped. So is there any possibility to disable restarting in PM2.

Comment: Don't run it with PM2 if you don't want it to restart, since that's its sole purpose.

Comment: But by using pm2-gui i am getting some visualized metrics of cpu and memory usage, thats why i am using pm2.

Comment: I assume that the question is to stop restarting the process after some condition inside the application was met (i.e. application stopped processing something... and it's not necessary to do anything more).

Comment: So others won't be misled by @BenFortune's comment: no, this is not PM2's sole purpose, at all. (If it were, they wouldn't have a --no-autorestart flag.) PM2 is also used for instrumentation; also it is used to automatically restart node apps on server reboot. Also used to email error notifications for paying customers.  Etc.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think you need the `--no-autorestart` flag.

"do not automatically restart apps"

http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/

Answer (score 8):

Simply `--no-autorestart` works like charm.
Usage example : `pm2 start script.js --no-autorestart`

Answer (score 5):

If you are using **pm2** using config json file e.g `pm2.config.json` or whatever then need to specify similar option **"autorestart"** to **false** in your json file.

```
"autorestart" : false
```

**E.g.**

I am using pm2 to run a java application using below json config file

```
{
  "apps" : [
    {
      "name":"JAVA-Pm2",
      "cwd":".",
      "script":"/usr/bin/java",
      "args":[
        "-jar",
        "/dir/my-java-app/build/libs/my-java-app-all.jar"
    ],
    "node_args":[],
    "exec_interpreter":"",
    "exec_mode":"fork",
    "autorestart" : false
  } 
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the pm2 config file, use

```js
"autorestart" : false
```

As suggested by @WitVault **BUT** make sure you don't have the `watch` option set to `true` like so:

```js
"watch": true   // This field should NOT be present, otherwise "autorestart" : false is ignored
```

Comment: Note: It seems the comment about `watch: true` making `autorestart:false` be ignored is outdated; I have `watch:"**"`, and adding `autorestart:false` successfully caused pm2 to not restart on my process erroring (with the restart-on-file-change still working).

Answer (score -1):

You can also list exit codes that don't cause pm2 to restart by using the --stop-exit-codes flag at pm2 launch this way you can still use pm2's auto restart feature but have it not restart on a clean exit https://blog.appsignal.com/2022/03/09/a-complete-guide-to-nodejs-process-management-with-pm2.html is a guide on using pm2 with node js you can do a process.stop specifying an exit code that pm2 is told to not restart with
I know this is a late response but I added it for future readers of this post